# Make changes to USB flash drive 'stick'

Tags: dconf

I'm using Ubuntu-Mate on a USB flash drive for some testing. I'm making some changes to the startup using dconf-editor but would like to somehow make these changes 'stick' when I reboot. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a persistent live drive. You can use the tool mkusb for that purpose. See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)